# django template looping through a list

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to loop through a simple list like

```
{% for x in y %}
<p>My name is {{ x }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

My vies is like this

```
def listloop(request):
    y= ['John', 'Julie', 'Pat']
    context ={'x':y}
    return render(requst, 'index.html', context)
```

But this showing blank page. Please help What I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: if your context `{'x':y}` then template `{{ x }}`
 will give you `y` output ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misnamed context variable in dict.  It shoould be:

```
def listloop(request):
    y = ['John', 'Julie', 'Pat']
    context = {'y': y} # 'y' instead of 'x'
    return render(requst, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. but can't understand why! shouldn't I have to put template variable as dictionary key in context. thanks for help @catavaran

Comment: But that's what catavaran did. You originally sent x but looped through y, which didn't exist.

Comment: may be i guess  @Maktabun will change the `for` loop iterate through `y`

Comment: This is how django templates work.  See description of `context` argument in the `render`'s documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Comment: @catavaran that's we know but Maktabun doesn't mention here .. whether he changed for loop or not ...